# Get a datetime format from a string in Python

Tags: python, datetime

Hello sorry for the ambiguous title, here's what I want to do :

I have a string:

```
month = '1406'
```

that corresponds to the month of June, 2014.

How can I dynamically say that that string represents the month of June and I specifically want the last day of the month.

So I want to write it in the format: `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` and have:

```
'2014-06-30 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the last day of a given month with the [`calendar.monthrange()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange). Turn your string into two integers (month, year), create a `datetime` object from the year, month and last day of the month:

```
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import monthrange

year, month = int(month[:2]), int(month[2:])
year += 2000  # assume this century
day = monthrange(year, month)[1]

dt = datetime(year, month, day)  # time defaults to 00:00:00
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from calendar import monthrange
>>> month = '1406'
>>> year, month = int(month[:2]), int(month[2:])
>>> year += 2000  # assume this century
>>> day = monthrange(year, month)[1]
>>> datetime(year, month, day)
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 30, 0, 0)
>>> print datetime(year, month, day)
2014-06-30 00:00:00
```

The default string conversion for `datetime` objects fits your desired format already; you can make it explicit by calling `str()` on it or by using the [`datetime.datetime.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) method, as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I get : `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` when I do datetime(year,month,day)

Comment: @salamey: Note that I imported `from datetime import datetime`. You must've done `import datetime` instead. In that case use `dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day)`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
import datetime

mon = '1406'
y, m = divmod(int(mon), 100)

dt = datetime.datetime(2000 + y + m // 12, m % 12 + 1, 1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print dt
```